# Create a text file and write to it when bool is false

Tags: c#, logging, console, console-application

Runing a console app. If `bool User` is `true`, i want to output text to console app.
if `bool User` is `false` I want to create a file and output text to there.

Works fine for `true`, and creates the text file `if false`, but does not save text to it.

Any ideas?

```
if (!user)
{
    Console.SetOut(File.CreateText(@".\log" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss") + ".log"));
    OutputHeader();
}

Console.WriteLine("Arg count is " + args.Length.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Show verbose output is = " + verbose.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use some logging framework like [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) or [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/features.html) (both available from NuGet) which allows to change log output from configuration file. E.g. for [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) you can specify two targets - one for log file with date pattern name, and second for console output:

```
<targets>
  <target xsi:type="File" name="f" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
          layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
  <target xsi:type="Console" name="c" />
</targets>
```

Then you can select which target to use

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="f" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using WriteAllText instead. Its simple and easy.

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(string filepath, string text);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, tell me if it works I didn’t have the time to test it yet:

```
if (user!=true)
{
 System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@".\log"+ DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss")+".log", "Arg count is " + args.Length.ToString()+"\nShow verbose output is = " + verbose.ToString());
}

Console.WriteLine("Arg count is " + args.Length.ToString()+"\nShow verbose output is = " + verbose.ToString()+"\n");
```